# Symfony2 - relative path in cache file

Tags: php, symfony, caching, path, relative-path

I work with Symfony2.
I want to prepare cached files before putting them on server (not the same machine).

Problem is in content files, because some of them consists absolute path to resources, for example:

```
file: ./dev/classes.php.meta , 
file: ./dev/templates.php,
file: ./dev/assetic/routing.yml

'WebProfilerBundle:Profiler:toolbar_item.html.twig' => '/var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/toolbar_item.html.twig',
```

Is there any way to change it into **relative** path?

Answer (score 0):

When [`TemplatePathsCacheWarmer`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/CacheWarmer/TemplatePathsCacheWarmer.php) runs, it is configured to use `kernel.cache_dir`. If you know the path of the installed application, you can override this by running `cache:warmup` [with an environment variable to replace the parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html):

```
SYMFONY__kernel__cache_dir=/srv/myapp/app/cache php app/console cache:warmup
```

I've had limited success with trying to use a relative path here (it is possible to pass in `"../"`, but I'm not 100% sure what the templates are relative to). This makes it tricky when you have variable app directory paths (e.g. timestamped release folders).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is to use the `warmup` process from the cache command.
Simply run the command to clear the cache without passing the `no-warmup` option:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

If you use the `no-warmup` option or manually delete the `cache` folder content, then you need to run the `warmup` command:

```
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/deployment-tools.html#c-clear-your-symfony-cache

Comment: cache:clear does the warmup automatically (unless you give the --no-warmup option).

Comment: @JakubZalas Thanks, I didn't know (I always delete the cache folder manually - bad habits probably - so I need to run the `warmup` command). I have edited my answer.

Comment: I know how to build cache files. 
The problem is with their content, that consist absolute links such as "/var/www/symfony".